# Getting 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException' when executing iOS Appium TestNG Test Cases on AWS Device Farm

Tags: appium-ios, aws-device-farm

I am using Appium Version 1.9.1 and framework build on Appium Java TestNG, but when i execute i on AWS Device Farm on real device i am getting following error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unhandled endpoint: /session/BC6E4901-43A6-4C66-913A-EBAF8482DD4B/wda/screen -- http://127.0.0.1:8100/ with parameters {
    wildcards =     (
        "session/BC6E4901-43A6-4C66-913A-EBAF8482DD4B/wda/screen"
    );
}

Same test cases works fine on local machine.Please suggest a solution for the above issue.

Comment: Can you please add your local Appium server logs and device farms logs?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I know the reason for this. I don't know the version of the WDA that's in Device Farm's standard environment. However, in the custom environment, it actually references two different versions of the WDA.

**test spec snippet**

```
  # The environment variables below will be auto-populated during run time.
  - echo "Start appium server"
  # The default WDA used is at DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1 (Supports versions iOS 12 and below), it is using commit f865d3. See (https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/tree/f865d32e78a5a8a15469bee30ed2f985d378575d)
  # If you need an older WDA version or need support for node modules, use the WDA at DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V0. (This version does not suport iOS 12)
```

So if you use the custom environment the /screen endpoint should exist.

Can you give that a shot and let me know the results?

[How to schedule a run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-test-run.html#how-to-create-test-run-console)

HTH

-James